# XML String to JSON output

Tags: json, xml, asp-classic

I have an XML response by querying an API

```
Set httpRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
httpRequest.Open "GET", url&"net/WebService.aspx?Login="&email&"&EncryptedPassword="&apikey&"&EDI_Name=Generic\"&filename, False
httpRequest.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
httpRequest.Send
```

using these codes.

This httpRequest brings me a XML string just like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmldata>
    <Table>
        <ProductID>37883</ProductID>
        <ProductCode>G-49211</ProductCode>
        <ProductName>Preludes &amp; Postludes for the year beginning 9-11-2001/Ferr�</ProductName>
        <StockStatus>2</StockStatus>
        <LastModified>2014-02-27T09:50:00-08:00</LastModified>
        <LastModBy>1</LastModBy>
        <ProductPopularity>110</ProductPopularity>
    </Table>
    <Table>
        <ProductID>56236</ProductID>
        <ProductCode>BIS-SACD-1701-02</ProductCode>
        <ProductName>Bach: B minor Mass / Suzuki - Bach Collegium Japan (2 CDs)</ProductName>
        <StockStatus>1</StockStatus>
        <LastModified>2015-02-23T13:25:00-08:00</LastModified>
        <LastModBy>1</LastModBy>
    </Table>
</xmldata>
```

How can I Convert this xml string into a JSON response

Comment: Mine is not .net :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You convert XML to JSON pretty easily using [Chilkat's](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/) XML component.

Once the XML is loaded, just recursively step through the tree and build the JSON object.

```
function parseNode(node,indent){
    var rtn={};
    var attrCnt = node.NumAttributes;
    var chldCnt = node.NumChildren;
    if( attrCnt != 0 || chldCnt != 0){ rtn[node.Tag]={};}
    if(attrCnt > 0){
        for(var i = 0; i <= attrCnt- 1; i++){
            rtn[node.Tag]["@" + node.GetAttributeName(i)] = node.GetAttributeValue(i);
        }
        if(chldCnt == 0){ rtn[node.Tag]["#value"] = node.Content;}
    }
    if(chldCnt > 0){
        var ctArr = {};
        for(var i = 0; i <= chldCnt - 1; i++){
            var cTag = node.GetChildTagByIndex(i);
            var numWithTag = node.NumChildrenHavingTag(cTag);
            ctArr[cTag] = numWithTag;
        }
        for(var c in ctArr){
            if(ctArr[c]==1){
                var nextNode = parseNode(node.GetNthChildWithTag(c,0),indent + "\t");
                rtn[node.Tag][c] = nextNode[c];
            }else{
                rtn[node.Tag][c] = [];
                for(var ci = 0;ci <= ctArr[c] - 1;ci++){
                    var nextNode = parseNode(node.GetNthChildWithTag(c,ci),indent + "\t");
                    rtn[node.Tag][c][ci] = nextNode[c];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(attrCnt == 0 && chldCnt == 0){ rtn[node.Tag] = node.Content;}
    return rtn;
}

var json={};
var xml = new ActiveXObject("Chilkat_9_5_0.Xml");
var success = xml.LoadXml(xmlStr);
if(success){
    json=parseNode(xml,"");
}
```

...and if you need this in a JSON string...

```
function stringify(obj) {
    var t = typeof (obj);
    if (t != "object" || obj === null) {
        if (t == "string") obj = '"' + obj + '"';
        return String(obj);
    } else {
        // recurse array or object
        var n, v, json = [], arr = (obj && obj.constructor == Array);
        for (n in obj) {
            v = obj[n];
            t = typeof(v);
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
                if (t == "string") {
                    v = '"' + v + '"';
                } else if (t == "object" && v !== null){
                    v = stringify(v);
                }
                json.push((arr ? "" : '"' + n + '":') + String(v));
            }
        }
        return (arr ? "[" : "{") + String(json) + (arr ? "]" : "}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no easy way to do that in VBScript / Classic ASP, unless you can find a 3rd party ActiveX control that do the job for you.

Otherwise, you will need to design/decide on your target JSON structure, e.g.

```
{[{"ProductID":37883,"ProductCode":"G-49211"}, {"ProductID":56236,"ProductCode":"BIS-SACD-1701-02"}]}
```

Then, enumerate the XML DOM and generate the JSON string accordingly, or try with a similar approach of transforming the XML using XSLT as describe at https://www.bjelic.net/2012/08/01/coding/convert-xml-to-json-using-xslt/